# STS Spring Project: Why is that HelloWorld example not working?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am new to Spring and currently trying the following **Hello World example** from the book ProSpring3:

```
package com.tutorials.prospring3.ch2;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

    public class HelloWorldSpringDI {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Initialize Spring ApplicationContext
            ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                    "META-INF/spring/app-context.xml");
            MessageRenderer mr = ctx.getBean("renderer", MessageRenderer.class);
            mr.render();
        }
    }
```

The ClassPathXmlApplicationContext instantiation is marked as the following error: "The constructor ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(String) refers to the missing type BeansException"

In addiation, when running the application the IDE displays a **build path problem:** "Archive for required library: 'C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar' in project 'ch2' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file"

As the spring-beans.jar (to which the BeansException class belongs) is part of my **Maven Dependencies** i wonder how that could happen.

[image: STS screenshot]

**Has anyone a suggestion how to solve that problem?**

Thanks in advance!

Jonas

Comment: have you tried doing a mvn clean, mvn install?

Comment: Clean your repository en redownload. Could be that a proxy or whatever corrupted the jar (could be partially downloaded etc.).

Comment: @david99world: how can that mvn clean be done?

Comment: @M.Deinum: I already did that twice!

Comment: in a command prompt in the directory where your pom.xml is, type "mvn clean", then type "mvn install"

Comment: What did you do twice? I was hinting at throwing away the .m2 directory and redowloading the whole internet (or only the .m2/repository/org.springframework directory would suffice). If the jar comes from a local repo (artifactory or such) it might be that yo need to clean that up to.

Comment: @M.Deinum: OK. I misunderstood that ... I will try it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to open the archive `C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar` with an application like WinZip. If that application indicates that the archive is corrupted as well, you should delete it and try again. (delete the entire `C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.0.6.RELEASE` directory and all its contents).
On the next build of your project, the archive will be downloaded again. If it still does not work and you are connecting to a local repository, you should contact the administrator.

Comment: I manually downloaded the spring-benas-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar as auto-download did not happen. But still it doesnt work. Now I get the following error message: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 ApplicationContext cannot be resolved to a type
 ClassPathXmlApplicationContext cannot be resolved to a type

 at com.tutorials.prospring3.ch2.HelloWorldSpringDI.main(HelloWorldSpringDI.java:15)`

Comment: That means that maven cannot locate this jar. Are you connecting to a maven repository on the internet or to a local one. And where did you download the Spring Beans jar from and where did you store it ?

Answer (score 4):

I konw your problem have out of date, i just want to help someone who gets the same problem, as i got the same problem and finished it.It's easy,just add the org.springframework.beans.jar to your project.

Answer (score 1):

Look like the dependency is missing from your project's classpath.
To resolve it

```
Right click on your project
Navigate to **Maven**
Click on **Update project**
```

If it does not resolve this problem then

Go to the path

> C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/
>   and delete the folder named as `spring-beans`

```
Now again Right click on your project
Navigate to **Maven**
Click on **Update project**
```

It will update/add the orphan/missing dependency of your project

Answer (score 0):

Two causes:

1. The issue could be with the corrupted Spring JARs .
   Remove the existing Spring  dependancies
   Add dependencies from :
   http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans/5.0.0.M5
   It ll solve the issue.

2.The indirect dependancies for beans are not sufficiently added.

Add the dependancies .

Sameer Sukumaran

Answer (score 0):

Go to :C:\Users(user_name(or)admin_name).m2\repository\org\springframework

Now, delete spring-beans and spring-expression folder.

Go to :Eclipse and then update the project by right clicking on the project maven>update project.
Eclipse will download the required files.ISSUE SOLVED :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was working with 4.2.2.RELEASE version of Spring, once I changed it to 4.2.0.RELEASE, the error dispeared. I hope this can help in your case too.